# Is minimum heap sorted by "default"

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, heap, min-heap

I just picked up "Introduction to algorithms", and I started implementing heaps and heapsort algorithm in c#.

Implementing a function that constructs a min/max heap from an array of doubles, i noticed that the constructed heap has some interesting properties.

A built minimum heap can be read left to right, and top to bottom (from root to leaves, by levels), and it will be sorted.

Is this a property of a minheap, or I am just unable to get a case which this property does not apply. Max heap doesnt work this way, atleast what i am getting here.

Output:

2345 7 34 6 3 5 4 5 1 2 3 2 1 3 1 3 2 1 (maxheap)

1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 5 5 6 7 34 2345 (minheap)

Thanks for any responses in advance!

Comment: Luck. Obviously it can't always work, because you can heapify in linear time but you can't (comparison) sort in linear time.

Comment: Havent thought of that earlier, so yeah, obviously just luck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heaps only have relation between Parent node and their respective child nodes.
There is no relation between nodes at same level.

```
For Min Heaps: Value of Parent node <= Value of its child nodes
For Max Heaps: Value of Parent node >= Value of its child nodes
```

So its not necessary for Min Heap to be sorted when travelled Top-to-Bottom,Left-to-Right. Its just a coincidence in your case.
*For eg*: Consider this sequence: **`1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 10, 9`**
[image: Heap for above sequence]
These are in MinHeapify order but clearly  **not** in sorted order.
Visit this [Interactive Heap Link](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/Heap.html) or [this link](http://visualgo.net/heap.html) for proper visualisation on how heap is built.

Answer (score 0):

To make the implementation of the heap more robust, people usually call the two operations which you can make to a node: `sift` and `percolate`

`sift` is bringing the node as much down as possible on the tree by switching the node with the best of the two sons you find.

there is a possible implementation of the `sift` procedure

```
 public void sift (int i)
    {
        while (i != 0)
        {
            if (compare(heapData[i], parentValue(i)))
            {
                switchValuesAtIndexes(parentIndex(i), i);
                i = parentIndex(i);
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }
```

`percolate` is bringing the node as much up as possible on the tree by switching the node with the parent.

```
public void percolate (int i)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (indexExists(leftIndex(i)) && (!indexExists(rightIndex(i)) && compare(leftValue(i), heapData[i]) || indexExists(rightIndex(i)) && compare(leftValue(i), rightValue(i)) && compare (leftValue (i), heapData[i])))
            {
                switchValuesAtIndexes(leftIndex(i), i);
                i = leftIndex(i);
            }
            else
                if (indexExists(rightIndex(i)) && (compare (rightValue(i), leftValue(i)) && compare (rightValue(i), heapData[i])))
                {
                    switchValuesAtIndexes(rightIndex(i), i);
                    i = rightIndex(i);
                }
            else
                break;
        }
    }
```

To build the heap, you will need to apply `sift` or `percolate` (or both) to each element of the array

To sort the heap you constructed you will have to print the first element (which is the best of all heap accorting to a comparer which you define, min, max, etc)
Then you will have to "overwrite" the first element with the last and delete the last and then you'll have to apply `sift` on the first element to bring it to it's right position in the heap. And you repeat until there's no element left in the heap